# file_get_contents() outputs text instead of an image

Tags: php, ajax

I have this code that is supposed to get the url from 
I believe it works, because it does output something (not an error)

```
<?php 
    $url = $_GET['image'];
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
    header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 
    echo "<img scr=\"" . imagejpeg($image, null, 100) . "\" />"; 
    ?>
```

Although, instead of an image, it outputs text... 
Maybe the problem is in the AJAX processing code:

```
function showImage(str) {

    if (str.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("show_image_input").innerHTML="";
      return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("show_image_input").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","parts/display_input.php?image="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

But it does it's job (output image if the url is valid)...
Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: You're outputting HTML when you passed a header that identifies the page as a JPEG image?

Comment: Wow, recursion in html

Answer (score 4):

`imagejpeg()` outputs the raw binary data of a jpeg, e.g. the garbage that starts off with `JFIF.....`. `<img>` html tags expect a **URL** pointing at the location of a file to load. This code will NEVER work as is.

Try

image.php:

```
<?php 

$url = $_GET['image'];
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 
imagejpeg($image)
```

html:

```
<img src="image.php?image=kittens.gif" />
```

instead.